Spring/Mongo Issue, Unable to connect to primary node in a replica set but able to connect to secondary
My Java Application is able to connect to two of the secondary instances of the replica set but not to the primary instance. error log below
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 90000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=mongo2:27019, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=3.5 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=mongo3:27020, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=5.5 ms, state=CONNECTED}, {address=mongo1:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]

I am running the replicaSet using colima docker instance and following are the lis to commands I followed,
# pull the official mongo docker container
docker pull mongo:4.2
# create network
docker network create my-mongo-cluster
# create mongos
docker run -d --net my-mongo-cluster -p 27018:27018 --name mongo1 mongo:4.2 mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27018
docker run -d --net my-mongo-cluster -p 27019:27019 --name mongo2 mongo:4.2 mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27019
docker run -d --net my-mongo-cluster -p 27020:27020 --name mongo3 mongo:4.2 mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27020
# add hosts in /etc/hosts
sudo vim /etc/hosts
# add the below line
127.0.0.1       mongo1 mongo2 mongo3
# setup replica set
docker exec -it mongo1 mongo -port 27018
config={"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo1:27018"},{"_id":1,"host":"mongo2:27019"},{"_id":2,"host":"mongo3:27020"}]}
rs.initiate(config)


This could be a problem with resource contention or high load on the primary.  Check the mongod log from the time of the connection attempt to see if it even saw the connection.

You need to give the new cluster some time to vote in a new primary.  Usually completes in a few seconds, but a low-powered host could cause this to take minutes.  Running rs.stats() will show the state of the replica set.  Also, unrelated - you are using version 4.2 which is no longer a supported version.  Since 4.2 MongoDB has released 4.4 (out of support), and 5.0 (end of life November 1, 2024).  Consider starting with a minimum supported version, such as 6.0

It would be helpful to see how the application is trying to connect.  Please include relevant application source code examples.
